# Python: failed installation of libpysal

Tags: python

I am trying to install [libpysal](https://pypi.org/project/libpysal/) on a `Mac OS Sierra Version 10.13.4`

Here what I did after different check:

```
pip install -U setuptools
sudo su pip install libpysal
```

and I get the following error

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-kypVTe/libpysal/
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing, in a virtualenv, without any 'sudo' or having to first install setuptools.  It appears to me that the 'libpysal' module's installer is just broken - or it's at least not compatible with the Mac and/or python 2.7.15.

BTW, your particular install steps worry me.  Why are you performing the first step without sudo and the second step with it?  That makes no sense to me.  I would think you'd want sudo on both.

Finally, I think your 'su' in that second command must be a typo.  That command won't even run, as 'su' expects a login name, and 'pip' either isn't a valid login name,  or is but then the command executed will be "install libpysal" - you don't need/want the 'su'.